# Pandas column search on a Dataframe,, complexity and optimisation for search function on Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, dictionary

Here i'm looking for the line index having a given value on one column called "word", note that df is a dataframe having many columns but sorted alphabetically on the column "word".
here is my function

```
def getIndex(df,givenword):
    index=df[df['word']==givenword].index.values[0]
    return index
```

The problem is that **df** is quite big *(around 10000k rows)*, this function is called in a loop of 30000 givenword. The search performance is awful,would you suggest a better implementation to optimize my function.

Comment: Please provide more details, input and expected output. From what you describe it seems that you can use isin

Comment: @DaniMesejo the output is the line number, the input is a dataframe df.
for example getIndex(dataset,"hello") will return the line index 570 (the index of this word).

Comment: Yes but you have 30000 different words right? And you are looping over them?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yes i've a list of words, from this list i've to check if it exists and return the index. so i loop for each word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the the DataFrame is sorted alphabetically use [searchsorted](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html), see the toy example below:

```
import pandas as pd

ser = pd.Series(["fox", "hello", "jump", "world"])
res = ser.searchsorted("jump")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

You can even pass the whole list of words, as below:

```
res = ser.searchsorted(["fox", "hello"])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1]
```

The time complexity of this approach is O(mlogn), where m is the amount of words being searched and n is the size of the DataFrame. **Note:** you need to check that the words do correspond  to the index, as `searchsorted` search the position where the word needs to be inserted.

An alternative would be to create a dictionary mapping words to first  occurrence, and then search for the words:

```
lookup = {key: value for key, value in zip(ser.values[::-1], ser.index[::-1])}
words = ["jump", "world"]

res = [lookup[word] for word in words]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3]
```

The time complexity of this approach is O(n + m).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `idxmax`:

```
def getIndex(df,givenword):
    index = df[df['word'] == givenword].idxmax()
    return index
```

`idxmax` would give the index of the first occurrence of the maximum value here, in this case `True`.